# Conditional Interface - TS & Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a user component that has a variable named user: Employee | Student; In my HTML I have an element

###### {{ user.coure ?? user.department }}

Now I'm getting an error in my HTML since some properties in Employee are not available on Student interface. I don't want to use "any" type or have different variables e.g. student and employee. What is the best way?

Example of the interface that I'm using:

```
// user.interface.ts
export BaseUser {
    id: number;
    firstName: string;
    middleName: string;
}

export Employee extends BaseUser {
    department: string;
}

export Student extends BaseUser {
    course: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom type guard function

```js
const isStudent = (user: Employee | Student): user is Student => {
  return "course" in user
}

const isEmployee = (user: Employee | Student): user is Employee => {
  return "department" in user
}

console.log(
  isStudent(user) ? user.course : user.department
)
```

You can use `isStudent` or `isEmployee` as you need. The compiler's control flow analysis will know that `user` is of type `Student` if `isStudent` returns `true`.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QKpasgbwFgAoZc5YAEwC5kQBXAWwCNoBuUi5GYKDMADk4TCHQFRQAc05kKTalQA2EYaPFhJIGaQC+pUqEixEKAKJMADkoD2ATwgoIAD0ggqGNJhx5CXClQQlnBQYKLgGlo6JPokhuDQ8EjIAMpgDIHgyC5uHl5YuNB+cuQINgz8YsgS0rKxpGUgAshSEGAAInBgcMgAvMgAFACUdBbW9o7IAD6p6ZlgfQB8xXoGJI3NDHijVrYOKDNpGRBZ-a0dXXDDaxsLwBhH832DW9A74-vTs8fgI8iv+Hu3yevWWxDkUDaFRAyAARGUKlhYZQYQDVusbE07hgxntJv0BgD3niDsCTmA-gDKJ5cRMUKDiuRIekoDDYYFgqFwmBkaB-nh0aQAPRC5AbGwqAB0tikhLwkoRlWQAH5lfzoJKOSEwuShg1MRgJRBpTZZf57o9yXLoEMVeqoArykq6ADNUFtdzSEMgA)

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful. I came up with the right solution using your example as a reference.

For those who has the same approach, you can look up TS' "Type Predicates" and "Discriminated unions."